# What does it mean this error First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this error First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty

In the next code and have no idea how to resolve. I checked other similar questions but no luck.

I also share the controller which seems the issue but still no idea how to fix it

```
<%= form_for @upload do |f| %>
  <% if @upload.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@upload.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this document from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
        <% @upload.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
            <li><%= message %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.file_field :file %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Controller: 
This what makes the thing in my app. But I don't see the issue.

```
class UploadsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :upload_params, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @uploads = Upload.all
  end

  def show
    send_data(@upload.file_contents,
              type: @upload.content_type,
              filename: @upload.filename)
  end

  def new
    @upload = Upload.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @upload = Upload.new(upload_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @upload.save
        format.html { redirect_to upload_path, notice: 'Document was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @upload }
      else
        format.html { render :new, notice: 'Wrong file' }
        format.json { render json: @upload.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @upload.update(upload_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @upload, notice: 'Document was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @upload }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @upload.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @upload.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to uploads_url, notice: 'Document was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private

  def set_upload
    @upload = Upload.find(params[:id])
  end

  def upload_params
    params.require(:upload).permit(:file)
  end
end
```

Comment: you need to have `@upload = Upload.new` on the controller which renders this form

Comment: In which view file you have that form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty obvious from the error I would say. The `@upload` object must not be `nil`. Please make sure you initiate that object before rendering this view (usually in the controller).

Looking at your controller code, please change the `before_action` to call `set_upload`.

`before_action :set_upload, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]`

Comment: thanks but I have no idea what to look could you please if you have a moment check my controller 
https://pastebin.com/xaNJGpgx

Comment: I added please check

Comment: I saw and that is gone. Thanks! I need to know now to know an alternative to this ApplicationRecord in Rails 4.2.6 if you know because in 5 you can write that but in 4.2.6 i need to change. Do you know something about it?

`class Upload < ApplicationRecord
  include csv_uploader_widget
  validate :file_size_under_one_mb, :csv_file_format
  before_save :upload_local

end`

Comment: please don't ask new questions in comments. your code is not formatted properly in comments, making it very hard to read and figure out what you are asking.